# Accuracy value doesn't match prediction result of my keras model

Tags: neural-network, keras

My code is listed below, and the training data and testing data can be found here:

[testing data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oxilVHMJ-iW8nEMnDIOPF01Aol8dTosp/view?usp=sharing)

[training data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zNQVAKCE5-kFk9z_MNhlXrMXUgwZjKT3)

The outputted accuracy is  0.55, however, when I save the prediction to a file and compared to the testing data's result. out of the 380 records, only 72  results are classified correctly. So how come I get an Accuracy = 0.55?

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import optimizers

def one_hot_encode_object_array(arr):
    '''One hot encode a numpy array of objects (e.g. strings)'''
    uniques, ids = np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True)
    return np_utils.to_categorical(ids, len(uniques))

fields = ['dataResult','HomeWin','Draw','AwayWin']
traindata =pd.read_csv('17-18.csv', usecols=fields)
train_X = traindata.values[:, 1:4]
train_Y = traindata.values[:, 0]
train_y_ohe = one_hot_encode_object_array(train_Y)

testdata =pd.read_csv('16-17.csv', usecols=fields)

test_X = testdata.values[:, 1:4]
test_Y = testdata.values[:, 0]
test_y_ohe = one_hot_encode_object_array(test_Y)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_shape=(3,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(train_X, train_y_ohe, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=1, validation_data=(test_X, test_y_ohe))
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_X, test_y_ohe, verbose=1)
print("Accuracy = {:.2f}".format(accuracy))
prediction = model.predict(test_X)
print(prediction)
np.savetxt('prediction.csv',prediction ,delimiter=',')
```

**Update:**
Turned out it is my stupidity, my fields are `fields = ['dataResult','HomeWin','Draw','AwayWin']`

When I feed the one hot encode function with train_Y, I thought [1,0,0] means HomeWin, [0,1,0] is Draw and [0, 0, 1] is awayWin.

Turned out [0, 0, 1] is homewin and [1,0,0]is awayWin.
Does anyone know a good way of converting one hot encode back to the label?

Comment: How exactly are you determining that there are only 72 correct predictions?

Answer (score 1):

Keras model categorical accuracy calculates how often predictions have maximum in the same spot as true values, and not the mean values:

```
categorical_accuracy = K.mean(K.equal(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)))
```

Consult further [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14415/how-does-keras-calculate-accuracy)

Comment: hi, mine is not binary class, the result is either homewin, draw or awaywin. so the loss is 'categorical_crossentropy'. still for all my 380 rows, a 0.57 accuracy should give me around 190 correct prediction?

Comment: Ah, that explains it! The categorical accuracy is different, I edited my answer accordingly. Please check out and upvote the original answer on datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: sorry, but I am not sure how a 0.57 accuracy gives only 72 correct prediction?

Comment: It checks for each of your three classes, how often the predicted values are maximum in the same location as the true values. You can try to calculate the categorical accuracy manually using the formula in the answer.

Comment: ok, seems I understand bit more now, should I use a different loss function?

Comment: Read about the available Keras metrics: https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.2.0/metrics/

Seems like categorical_accuracy should do the trick in your case, but you can try a few others.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code. You are using train for test!!!

Change

```
test_X = traindata.values[:, 1:4]
test_Y = traindata.values[:, 0]
```

with

```
test_X = testdata.values[:, 1:4]
test_Y = testdata.values[:, 0]
```

Comment: that was a human error when I copied my code to stackoverflow. didn't do that in my notebook.